# Where did the seemingly erroneous identification of the star destroyer Avenger originate?

Tags: star-wars

About fifteen or twenty years ago, I was discussing *The Empire Strikes Back* with my brother and some of his friends.  (All the participants were huge *Star Wars* fans, and my brother and his friends were active players of the *Star Wars* role-playing game at the time.)  I mentioned how the rebels escaping from Hoth used their ion cannon to disable the star destroyer that was in their flight path.  Somebody (my brother or one of his friends, I don't recall) said, "Oh, that's the Avenger," and they showed me a source that agreed with that (a manual from the RPG, I think).

My response was that that almost certainly wasn't right.  The Avenger is the only star destroyer named in dialogue in *Empire*, but it's clear from the context ("Sir, we have a priority signal from the star destroyer Avenger.") that the Avenger is the ship that locates the Millennium Falcon when it leaves the asteroid field.  We later see what ship that is, as it's chasing after the Falcon; it's Captain Needa's ship.

Since we saw who the captain of the disabled ship was, and it wasn't Needa, this strongly suggests that the disabled ship was not the Avenger.  (It doesn't make it impossible, but all evidence militates against the identification of the Avenger as that ship.)  So where did the idea that that was the Avenger originate?  Was it just sloppy work on the part of some extended universe writer, or what?

Comment: This is kind unclear. Why do you think the captain of the disabled ship isn't Needa?

Comment: The captain of the disabled ship has a scene, and dialogue.  "Sir, Rebel ships are coming into our sector."  "Good. Our first catch of the day."  I just Googled that dialogue and found from Wookieepedia that some sources, at least, correctly identify his ship as a different one (named Tyrant).

Comment: The *Tyrant* was disabled during the Battle of Hoth. The *Avenger* wasn't chasing the *Falcon* until later.

Comment: Perhaps I need to go rewatch the movie, its been awhile.

Comment: @amflare No, that's all correct!  However, there were at least some sources that said that it was the Avenger that was disabled, and I wanted to know where that mistake originated.

Comment: So to be clear, someone somewhere thinks the Avenger was the disabled one and not the one chasing the Falcon, and you want to know where that started?

Comment: Some official source(s) said that, yes.  And I want to know where that started, yes.

Comment: Wookiepedia's [Legends article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Avenger/Legends) on the Avenger talks about it having both been commanded by Needa _and_ disabled at Hoth.

Comment: Of course, given Vader's propensity to choke out any high ranking official who disappoints him, it's not unexpected that command of ships changes often!

Comment: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwarscardtrader/images/0/07/TorynFarr-White-Back.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/534?cb=20170911012742 - Confirmed as the Tyrant. Captained by [Captain Lennox](https://www.tcdb.com/Images/Cards/Gaming/122192/122192-8287767Fr.jpg)